# What is the story of Latin letters U, V?

Tags: phonetics, ancient-greek

I recently saw a video stating that when the Romans imported the `upsilon`(`Y`) from Greek, they cut the the bottom line from `Y` and remained `V` which was not read as `V` as we know but `U`. So
`V(letter)` = `U(sound)` and `V(sound)` and `U(letter)` didn't existed, and `U(letter)` was invented when by hurrying the scribes didn't make the `V` sharp, but round as `U`. The Greek and Cyrillic script didn't have this problem because `B(letter)` = `V(sound)`.

But I can't believe that  `Ave Caesar` was pronounced `Aooe Caesar`, or `Vezuvius` as `Ooezooiu`, or `Veni, vidi, vici` as `Weni, Wedee, Wici` or `Viva` as `Wewa`. And if this is the case why do we learn Latin in school with `V(sound)` if it didn't exist?

Comment: Hi and welcome to Language Learning Stack Exchange. This is a site for questions about methods and hard-to-find resources for learning to teaching languages. Questions about features of specific languages or their development are off topic here. If you want, I can migrate your question to a site where it is on topic.

Comment: Then migrate it

Comment: FWIW, I did actually learn to say, "Weni, Wedee, Wici" at school.